# How to use grep to get special character

Tags: unix

I want to grep \" as following text in file(abc) like:

```
$egrep -n  "^\"$" abc
"CO_FA_SC_600212","2","\"HSE 48\" 48 CHIVALRY AVE"
```

But its not appearing how could i use egrep or grep to get the line.

Comment: What pattern do you want to match exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -F 'special char' filename` will search the lines which has special characters.

`grep -Fn 'special char' filename` gets the line number too.

[man grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) says,
`-F, --fixed-strings`: Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched

Answer (score 1):

Here are two alternatives:

1. `grep -n "\\\\\"" filename`
2. `grep -n '\\"' filename`
3. For the first one, two consecutive `\\` act as a single `\`, and `"` was escaped by `\`, so `\\"` is passed to `grep`.
4. For the second one, `\` is taken literally, so `\\"` is passed to `grep`
5. `3` and `4` can be verified by `echo "\\\\\""` and `echo '\\"'`